# Combining memoization and SlotSequence

Tags: memoization, slot

I found myself writing memoizing code like this:

```
p[k1_] := p[k1] = b^0 a[k1];
p[k1_, k2_] := p[k1, k2] = p[k1] + b^1 a[k1 + k2];
p[k1_, k2_, k3_] := p[k1, k2, k3] = p[k1, k2] + b^2 a[k2 + k3];
p[k1_, k2_, k3_, k4_] := 
  p[k1, k2, k3, k4] = p[k1, k2, k3] + b^3 a[k3 + k4];
p[k1_, k2_, k3_, k4_, k5_] := 
  p[k1, k2, k3, k4, k5] = p[k1, k2, k3, k4] + b^4 a[k4 + k5];
```

and so on, where `a` is some function that is unimportant, and `b` is a constant.

Is there a one-liner for the "and so on" part, perhaps using `SlotSequence`? The issue is that `##n` only allows you to start at positive integers, which makes things difficult (since for example in `p[k1, k2, k3, k4, k5] = p[k1, k2, k3, k4] + a[k4 + k5]` it uses a combination of the first four and the last two arguments). Might there be a simple way around this?

Comment: You also could use something like this:  `ClearAll[p]; p[x_] := p[x] = b^0*a[x];
p[fst___, x_, y_] := p[fst, x, y] = p[fst, x] + b^(Length[{fst}] + 1)*a[x + y]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way using `BlankNullSequence`:

```
Clear[p];
p[k_] := p[k] = a[k]
pk : p[k0___, k1_, k2_] := pk = p[k0, k1] + b^Length[{k0, k1}] p[k1 + k2]
```

We can test this on an example:

```
p[k1, k2, k3, k4, k5]
(* a[k1] + b a[k1 + k2] + b^2 a[k2 + k3] + b^3 a[k3 + k4] + b^4 a[k4 + k5] *)
```

And then check `Definition[p]` to make sure the values were correctly memoized:

```
p[k1]=a[k1]
p[k1+k2]=a[k1+k2]
p[k2+k3]=a[k2+k3]
p[k3+k4]=a[k3+k4]
p[k4+k5]=a[k4+k5]
p[k1,k2]=a[k1]+b a[k1+k2]
p[k1,k2,k3]=a[k1]+b a[k1+k2]+b^2 a[k2+k3]
p[k1,k2,k3,k4]=a[k1]+b a[k1+k2]+b^2 a[k2+k3]+b^3 a[k3+k4]
p[k1,k2,k3,k4,k5]=a[k1]+b a[k1+k2]+b^2 a[k2+k3]+b^3 a[k3+k4]+b^4 a[k4+k5]
p[k_]:=p[k]=a[k]
pk:p[k0___,k1_,k2_]:=pk=p[k0,k1]+b^Length[{k0,k1}] p[k1+k2]
```

I personally like to define the base cases for recursive functions using patterns instead of `If`-statements, and since Mathematica has extremely fast pattern matching there isn't a performance hit.

So, we define the base case (`p` called with one element) first.  This uses one method of memoization, where we duplicate the pattern (`p[k_]`) in the LHS of `Set` (`p[k]`).

This can be a little clumsy or error-prone for more complex memoizations, so I use another method in the second definition: giving the whole pattern a name (`pk : _`), and then just using that name in the assignment (`pk = _`).

As for the second pattern itself, we need to name the last two arguments (`k1_` and `k2_`), since they are both referenced explicitly.  However, the rest of the arguments don't need to be named individually, so we can match a sequence (`k0___`).  We don't use `BlankSequence` (`__`), since we need to handle cases with only two arguments, where `k0` will end up being just `Sequence[]`.

After figuring out the arguments, it's simple to write the function.  Just remember that you can't do something like `Length[k0]`: for `p[a, b, c, d]` that would end up `Length[a, b]`.  You'd want `Length[{k0}]`, which ends up `Length[{a, b}]`.

Comment: And how is this any different in any non-trivial way from Leonid' s comment?

Comment: @rasher oops, didn't notice that comment ;;0_0 Guess it was posted while I was writing.  The solutions themselves are totally identical, yeah... can I split the rep with him?  What's procedure here?

Comment: It happens - done it myself. I delete to give commenter time to make it answer - particularly when an expert/regular,  if that doesn't happen, fair game.

Comment: @rasher Comments are not supposed to be actual answers. But they can provide a light-weight way to answer or give hints. If someone takes a comment of someone else and posts this (or similar) as an answer, this is totally fine, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to go about it.

```
Clear[p];
p[k_] := p[k] = If[Length[k] > 1, 
  p[Drop[k, -1]] + b^(Length[k] - 1) a[k[[-2]] + k[[-1]]], a[First[k]]];
```

For example:

```
p[{k1, k2, k3, k4, k5}]

a[k1] + b a[k1 + k2] + b^2 a[k2 + k3] + b^3 a[k3 + k4] + b^4 a[k4 + k5]
```